# What is the name of the bias that associate a thing as good because it has a relation to another good thing?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, bias, psychology, behavioral-economics

A customer buys X from "brand A" and has positive experience with it. "Brand A" also sells Y. Now the customer things it is good to buy Y because of his/her positive experience with buying X from brand A and that since it was good, buying Y from brand A should also be good. They bought Y because of association.

What would be the name of the psychological process or cognitive bias that lead the customer to buy Y ?

Comment: The title is not really representative of what you are asking; could you update it so that it is more searchable for people with a similar question to yours?

Answer (score 9):

It's called the [Halo Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect#Branding):

> The halo effect is a ... cognitive bias, where a person making an
>   initial assessment of another person, place, or thing will assume
>   ambiguous information based upon concrete information.
>
> The term halo effect is used in marketing to explain customer bias
>   toward certain products because of favorable experience with other
>   products made by the same company. ... A notable example is the manner
>   in which the popularity of Apple’s iPod generated enthusiasm for the
>   corporation's other products.